# How complex can my bitcoin wallet encryption key be?

Tags: client, encryption

What are the requirements and limitations of the password that the satoshi bitcoin wallet allows the user to set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The password must be at least 1 character long.  I've not been able to find a maximum length.  I set the passphrase to be a 100,000 character string, and that worked fine.  Missing the last character off the end of the long string didn't work, so the 100,000th character is significant.

When first setting a passphrase the satoshi client requests that your passphrase be at least 10 random characters or 8 random words.  But it doesn't attempt to enforce its request.